# How can I find what quarter of the year a month is in based on the number the month corresponds to

Tags: javascript

I am on codewars, here is the challenge:

> Given a month as an integer from 1 to 12, return to which quarter of the year it belongs as an integer number.
> For example: month 2 (February), is part of the first quarter; month 6 (June), is part of the second quarter; and month 11 (November), is part of the fourth quarter.

Here is what I tried:

```
const quarterOf = (month) => {
  // Your code here
  if (month <= 3) {
    return 1
  } else if (6 >= month > 3) {
    return 2
  } else if (9 >= month > 6) {
    return 3
  } else if (12 >= month > 9) {
    return 4
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, I know I could assign each month a variable, but I'm trying to improve my skills, can someone explain why this does not work to me?

Comment: You're looking for the logical (boolean) operator `&&`, which implies that you might wanna learn some basic programming before moving forward.

Comment: You can also just `return Math.ceil(month / 3)`, but don't ignore the advice about taking some basic programming tutorials first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java Math.ceil(month / 3) solution doesn't work as expected, as it returns double.

```
public static int quarterOf(int month) {
    return month % 3 == 0 ? (month / 3) : (month / 3) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple you are trying to check for two conditions in one statement try to use && and || for separation of conditions your code will look like this:

```js
const quarterOf = (month) => {
  // Your code here
  if (month <= 3) {
  return 1
  } else if (6 >= month && month > 3) {
    return 2
  } else if (9 >= month && month > 6) {
    return 3
  } else if (12 >= month && month > 9) {
    return 4
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function monthChecker(month){
    if (month < 4){
        return greeting `Yeah ! It's the first quarter of the year....`;
    }
    else if (month  > 4 && month < 6){
        return `Yeah ! It's the second quarter of the year....`;   
    }
    else if (month > 7 && month < 9 ){
        return `Yeah ! It's the third quarter of the year....`;
    }
    else if (month > 9 && month < 12){
        return `Yeah ! It's the last quarter of the year....`;
    }
    else{
        return `This isn't within the months in a year, enter a valid month number`
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you even test that? Month 4, 6, 9 and 12 are not handled correctly. What does your answer add to the already provided answers?